# Apache Flink: How can I reload an updated jar without restarting my job?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, dynamic-class-loaders

My Flink job has a jar file provided by the client, which I can store in /lib folder. Is there a way to reload the updated jar file, without restarting the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible with the current version (Flink 1.4.0, Dec 2017).

Flink offers [savepoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/state/savepoints.html) to save the state of an application. 
If you want to change the code (or dependencies) of an application, zou have to take a savepoint, update the code/dependencies, and restart the application from the savepoint.

This technique can also be used to scale an application up or down or to migrate it.

Comment: Thanks. Is this in scope for any future versions?

Comment: I'm not aware of efforts in this direction. The community is working on much faster savepoint and recovery cycles. If a job is temporarily stopped (i.e., no failure happened), data can be saved locally and the processes just be restarted.